# Phrasal verb clarification

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> I intend to see it **carried out**

Can we use a phrasal verb as an **adverb** or **modifier**?
In the above sentence I think **carried out** is used as modifier.

If the function of **carried out** is different then please explain me properly. Thanks

Comment: The transitive multi-word verb 'carry out' can be replaced by 'do' or 'complete' here. This question then asks about the function of 'done' in 'I intend to see it done'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*I intend to see it carried out*

is probably best interpreted as a shortened form of

*I intend to see that it is carried out.*

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see) lists the relevant sense of *see*:

> **see** verb (MAKE CERTAIN) ​
>
> C2 [ + (that) ] [which may often be deleted] to make certain that
>   something happens:
>
> [UK] *See (that) you're ready by five, or there'll be trouble.*
>
> *The receptionist said he will see (that) she is warned.* [modified to fit example here]

**So the string 'carried out' is verbal, not modifying 'it'.** Replacing the transitive multi-word verb by a simplex synonym,

*I intend to see it finished* / *I intend to see that it is finished.*

.................

With 'I intend to see it finished', there *is* an alternative reading where 'finished' post-modifies the pronoun:

*'I don't like seeing a half-built building; I intend to see it
finished'*

(with the usual sense for 'see').

And for the literal sense,

*The man carried out on a stretcher was her brother*

uses what some would see as a whiz-deleted construction – a reduced relative clause – modifying '[the] man'.

Answer (score 0):

A modifier can be taken out without affecting the sentence structure. I do not think that is he case here.

I also think that the part that is to be named is "it carried out" as your sentence essentially is a variation of "I intend to see to X"

so in effect it is two phrasal verbs, one as object.